# Parsing of the site booking.uz.gov.ua

Tags: java, html, json, parsing

This code that parses from the site booking.uz.gov.ua. But for some reason, he did not want to work. Who can show why does not work, or fix it?
Who can advise something?

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at ua.gov.uz.booking.uz.main(uz.java:137)

```
package ua.gov.uz.booking;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class uz {

static String html   = "";
static String cookie = "";
static String token  = "";
static String error  = "";

static Map<String, List<String>> headers = null;

static void fetchHtml() {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://booking.uz.gov.ua/");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        headers = conn.getHeaderFields();
        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            html += line;
        }
        rd.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        error = e.getMessage();
    }
}

static void parseCookie() {
    List<String> cookies = headers.get("Set-Cookie");
    for (String current_cookie : cookies) {
        if (current_cookie.startsWith("_gv_sessid")) {
            cookie = current_cookie;
            break;
        }
    }
}

static void parseToken() {
    String adapter = "var token;localStorage={setItem:function(key, value){if(key==='gv-token')token=value}};";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\$\\$_=.*~\\[\\];.*\"\"\\)\\(\\)\\)\\(\\);");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(html);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        String obfuscated = matcher.group(0);
        ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
        try {
            engine.eval(adapter + obfuscated);
        } catch (ScriptException e) {
            error = e.getMessage();
        }
        token = engine.get("token").toString();
    }
}

static String getStationId(String name) {
    String json = "";
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://booking.uz.gov.ua/en/purchase/station/" + name + "/");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            json += line;
        }
        rd.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        error = e.getMessage();
    }
    ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    engine.put("json", json);
    try {
        engine.eval("var station_id = JSON.parse(json).value[0].station_id");
    } catch (ScriptException e) {
        error = e.getMessage();
    }
    return engine.get("station_id").toString();
}

static String getData(String fromName, String toName, String date) {
    fetchHtml();
    parseCookie();
    parseToken();
    String from = getStationId(fromName);
    String to = getStationId(toName);
    String json = "";
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://booking.uz.gov.ua/en/purchase/search/");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);
        conn.setRequestProperty("GV-Token", token);
        conn.setRequestProperty("GV-Ajax", "1");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Referer", "http://booking.uz.gov.ua/en/");
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        String urlParameters = MessageFormat.format("station_id_from={0}&station_id_till={1}&date_dep={2}" +
                                                    "&time_dep=00:00&time_dep_till=24:00", from, to, date);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            json += line;
        }
        rd.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        error = e.getMessage();
    }
    return json;
}

static String getData(String fromName, String toName) {
    return getData(fromName, toName, new SimpleDateFormat("MM.dd.yyyy").format(new Date()));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {


if (args.length < 2) {
    System.out.println("Онлайн резервування та придбання квиткiв - Укрзалізниця");
    System.out.println("Введите: <start_station> <end_station> [MM.DD.YYYY]");
    System.exit(1);
}
String data;
if (args.length > 2)
    data = getData(args[0], args[1], args[2]);
else
    data = getData(args[0], args[1]);
System.out.println(data);
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Line 137 is args[0] = "dsa". If 0 is an IndexOutOfBound, this means that args is an array with size 0 (i.e. empty). Therefore, you cannot access its index 0, because that requires an array with size >= 1.

How are you launching the program affects the content of the args array (that contains the parameters passed to the program when launched via console). Have you checked what args is when launching with a breakpoint? How do you launch your program? (in the ide, or via console?)

Comment: Fixed main().  but in the console displays me: Онлайн резервування та придбання квиткiв - Укрзалізниця
Введите: <start_station> <end_station> [MM.DD.YYYY]. And I can not enter: "start station" and "end station"

Comment: @RomanKostetskyy Console errors in cyrillic are not so helpful on a website where everyone speaks english. Please translate the message to english or we can't help you

Comment: Fixed main(). but in the console displays me: On-line booking and purchasing tickets - Ukrzaliznytsia.  Enter: <start_station> <end_station> [MM.DD.YYYY]. And I can not enter: "start station" and "end station"

Comment: Thats still in the main. You are providing less than 2 arguments. Look at your main if (args.length < 2)

Comment: you can help, how to fix it?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it: this program requires at least 2 inputs in the args array: the startDate and endDate strings in the MM.DD.YYYY format. If you are invoking it via console, run with "myProgram 11.24.2015 11.25.2015", if you are running from IDE, change the main so that the first line is args = new String[2]; args[0] = "11.24.2015"; args[1] = "11.25.2015";

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
  args = new String[2];
  args[0] = "07.16.2015";
  args[1] = "08.16.2015";
  System.out
    .println("Online booking and purchasing tickets - Railways");
  System.out.println("Enter: <start_station> <end_station> [MM.DD.YYYY]");
  System.out.println(args);
 }

Comment: Roman, the program IS right. Your way of invoking it is not. Your modifications as posted in the alst comment will allow it to run, as well as print out the args.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are running your program directly from main method then initialize `args`. If you are calling main method from other program then you don't have to initialize `args`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    args = new String[5];
    args[0] = "dsa";
    .......
}
```

Comment: Fixed main(). but in the console displays me: Онлайн резервування та придбання квиткiв - Укрзалізниця Введите: <start_station> <end_station> [MM.DD.YYYY]. And I can not enter: "start station" and "end station"